# Custom LightDM sessions to launch an application

Tags: lightdm, gnome-session

I'm trying to set up Ubuntu to act as a kiosk running a custom application, and am trying to get a LightDM session built to automatically start it.

Ideally, I'd like to have two sessions available from LightDM. The default would start my application fullscreened, and the other would open a minimal desktop in case any configuration (mostly connecting to a wireless network) needed to be done.

I've done a lot of research over the last week on custom LightDM & Gnome sessions. I've got a custom greeter written for LightDM that can start either session, but I can't figure out how to add a specific application to the Gnome session that is ultimately started without just putting a launcher in the global startup directory, and I don't want to do that since I don't want the application starting when they open "configuration mode".

Another problem I've run into on my current workaround is that the application doesn't fullscreen properly, which makes me think I'm not starting enough of a gnome session (currently it's just metacity, no panel or anything else).

Edit:

I found a solution. See http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/make-applications-autostart-only-in.html

Comment: Glad you found the answer. Can you please consider adding it as an answer to this question and marking it as solved? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at gnome startup applications?  It's possible it won't work running a pretty naked install like that. `gnome-session-properties` Is the generic way to do it.  Let me know if it doesn't work and I'll delete it.

Comment: The problem is I don't want it to start on each session. Does this only autostart for that session?

Comment: Yes.  It autostarts on login for the session, but it isn't global for all users...It's per user.

Comment: I'm using the same user on each session, and adding an application through gnome-session-properties starts it on both sessions.

Comment: Oh, I would have thought you would have a configuration user and a using user...deleting soon

Comment: I guess that's a potential workaround, but I figure there has to be a way to define a custom session including a set of particular applications